# Naming data providers in unittests

Tags: unit-testing, naming-conventions

When writing a parameterized unit test how do you call the method that supplies the parameters (in TestNG called `DataProvider`)?

Does a best practice exist? Can you point me to some literature that discusses the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not calling it in a generic way, but use the domain language, so each test will clearly say what does it do, with different factory methods.

Going even further, I would discourage parametrized tests, as they're not really readable (usually, maybe in your scenario this is not the case). If the test set up is complicated, then you should redesign your code, for the sake of simpler tests.

A nice and short presentation summarizing a very good book on this topic: http://www.slideshare.net/agileee/clean-tests.